# Midi Clip breaks Sustain Pedal on my Piano Track

Tags: piano, sustain

I'm not sure what's happening but this one clip, whenever I play it or change anything in it just seems to turn off all sustain on my piano and it's driving me insane, I don't know what's causing it... any help would be extremely appreciated!

Comment: Difficult, until you find a way to share the .MID file with us.

Comment: I don't really know what happened but I could fix it by just automating the reverb on/off to force it on. I don't know why, but that fixed it... the problem is, I'm on a huge time crunch, have to finish my song today, so every complication has me stressed out of my mind '^^

Comment: Are we talking about sustain as in the sustain pedal on a piano, or sustain as produced by reverb?

Answer (score 1):

Pure guess, based on little to no information…

There will be a pedal up [CC64 0] near the beginning of the track & your DAW has some kind of "event chasing" going on.
Either find the pedal event in list edit or disable the event chasing.